# Javascript libraries not loading on window.open tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I have a word matching exercise game that is written in javascript and html. When the user clicks add more the add_more() method adds a new key, description pair to the keys and descriptions input boxes.

Expected: The user clicks render html then A new tab appears with the rendered html. The user should be able to drag and drop the keys onto the descritpions.

Actual: The user clicks render html then A new tab appears with the rendered html. The drag and drop functionality does not work. The javascript libraries are not loading properly.

[The code for this game is quite simple.](https://github.com/EvanGertis/Selected-Topics/blob/main/wordMatch/Section5_3.html)

The issue occurs in this method.

```
function render_html(){
      textarea  = document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea");
      // Set the generate html to the value from the textarea.
      generated_html = textarea.value;
      console.log(generated_html);
      // Create a new tab.
      var new_window = window.open('');
      maincontentstyle = document.getElementById("maincontentstyle");
      rendered_html = document.createElement("div");
      rendered_html.setAttribute("id","rendered_html");
      rendered_html.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
      rendered_html.innerHTML +=  generated_html;
      rendered_html.innerHTML +='<span style="padding: 3px"> <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="show_answer()">Show Answer</button> <button id = "resetButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="reset()">Reset</button> </span>';
      results = document.getElementById("results");
      // Append the rendered html to the results tab
      results.appendChild(rendered_html);
      htmlRendered = true;
      header = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>Word Matching Exercise</title>\n\t\t<style>\n*:focus {outline: 2px solid blue; outline-offset: 2px;}\n\t\tdetails {padding:3px;}\n\t\t</style>\n\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"boxes.css?v=9999\" />\n\t\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"event1.js?v=9999\">';
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>\n<script async src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-89940905-27\">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>\n<script>\n\t window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\n\t function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};\tgtag(\"js\", new Date());\tgtag(\"config\", \"UA-89940905-27\");\n'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>\n'
      header += '<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>'
      header += '<script src="jquery-ui.min.js">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>'
      header += '<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>'
      header += '<script src="jquery.alerts.js">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>'
      header += '<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">'
      header += '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"../logging.js\">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>\n</head>\n\t\t<body>';
      new_tab_html = header;
      new_tab_html += rendered_html.innerHTML;
      footer = '\n\t\t</body>\n</html>\n';
      footer += '<script type="text/javascript" src="GetElementPosition.3.js">'
      footer += '</'
      footer += 'script>'
      footer += '<script>audioOn = false; $(function() {$(\'.menulink\').click(function(){if (audioOn) {$("#bg").attr(\'src\',\"../audioOff.png\");  audioOn = false;}else {$(\"#bg\").attr(\'src\',"../audioOn.png");audioOn = true; speak(" ");}return false;});});'
      footer += '</'
      footer += 'script>'
      footer += '<img id="bg" src="../audioOff.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;">'
      new_tab_html += footer;
      console.log(new_tab_html);
      new_window.document.write(new_tab_html);
    }
```

The javascript libraries are using relative paths.

[image]

Comment: What errors does the developer console in your browser show in the new tab?

Comment: There aren't any errors showing up.

Comment: Not even in the Network tab? I was thinking of a 404 for any of those external resources (js, imgs) given that the tags have the relative paths to them.

Comment: I would suspect the relative paths first. You might want to switch them to URL paths to ensure there is no ambiguity since the new HTML is not generated by the Server. The browser will not know where "jquery-1.7.2.min.js" is for example, since it's on the server. So I would switch them all to a Fully Qualified URL Paths.

Comment: @Twisty I've updated the question.

Comment: @EvanGertis when the new HTML loads, how does it know where the Scripts are as there is no Relative Path to the newly rendered HTML? You need to specify the Full Path.

Comment: @Twisty it just loads from the current directory.

Comment: @EvanGertis the newly created HTML has no relationship with the server. Therefore, there is no *current directory*.

Comment: @Twisty I'm using `new_window.document.write(new_tab_html);` to write the html to the new tab.

Comment: @EvanGertis use Full Paths instead of Relative Paths.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to move the application into a web application that followed web MVC design pattern. Rather than rendering HTML and javascript in a new tab a separate view is generated with an associated id that can be shared with the user.